# Generate Binary Outcome Based on Given ProbabilitY

Tags: python, random

I'm writing code that requires the generation of a binary outcome from a given probabilities or list. I'm looking at the random module but was unable to find anything that would solve the problem.

Example

RETURN 1 30% of the time

EXAMPLE

RETURN 1 OR 0 45% and 55% of the time

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Python language

Answer (score 2):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random.choices#random.choices) will certainly do what you want, but it might be overkill. It can generate an arbitrarily long sequence of choices from a finite set where each element has an independent frequency. There is an example of its use in the examples section of the linked Python documentation:

```
>>> # Estimate the probability of getting 5 or more heads from 7 spins
>>> # of a biased coin that settles on heads 60% of the time.
>>> trial = lambda: choices('HT', cum_weights=(0.60, 1.00), k=7).count('H') >= 5
>>> sum(trial() for i in range(10000)) / 10000
0.4169
```

In that example, the weights are specified as a cumulative distribution:

```
cum_weights=(0.60, 1.00)
```

An equivalent call using individual weights, as in your example, would be

```
weights=(0.60, 0.40)
```

The weights don't need to add up to 1; they will be normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a uniform(0,1) random value, check if it's ≤ the desired proportion/p-value, and return 0 or 1 accordingly.  Assuming `rand` is a U(0,1) generator, pseudocode would look like this:

```
function bernoulli(p) {
  if rand <= p {
    return 1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
```